# Assistance with regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need help with a regex pattern that allows me to do the below but I'm not quite sure how to.

```
command, extra = re.search(SomeRegexPattern, string).groups() # or split it to be a list

Input: ".SomeCommand"
command, extra = "SomeCommand", "" # extra is "" because there was nothing that follows "SomeCommand"
Input: ".SomeCommand Some extra stuff"
command, extra = "SomeCommand", "Some extra stuff"
Input: ".SomeCommand Some really long text after SomeCommand"
command, extra = "SomeCommand", "Some really long text after SomeCommand"
```

***Note SomeCommand is dynamic it is not actually SomeCommand***

Is there a regex that makes this possible? So that the command is one thing and anything that comes after the command is assigned to extra?

***Update***:
It seems I have not clarified enough of what the regex should do so I'm updating the answer to help.

```
while True:
    text = input("Input command: ")
    command, extra = re.search(SomeRegexPattern, text).groups()
```

**Example data**

```
# when text is .random 
command = "random"
extra = ""

# when text is .gis test (for google image search.)
command = "gis"
extra = "test"

# when text is .SomeCommand Some rather long text after it
command = "SomeCommand"
extra = "Some rather long text after it"
```

***Working Regex***

`command, extra = re.search("\.(\w+)( *.*)", text).groups() # modified zhangxaochen's answer just a tad and it works, don't forget to redefine extra as extra.strip()`

Comment: It's not clear how this pattern is supposed to behave. Why does the second example drop the `Some` from the output? Why is the period removed? Should other kinds of leading characters be removed too? Would merely `split`ting the string produce output you can use?

Comment: @user2357112 Typo on my part, i'll edit it

Comment: @user2357112 I forgot to address your second question about the leading characters and splitting, but I think regex is better for this problem then trying to split the string. As for the leading characters, if I understand it correctly any character should work no matter if it is a digit, letter, decimal, or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
In [179]: cmd = 'SomeCommand'

In [180]: s = '.SomeCommand Some extra stuff'

In [189]: command, extra = re.search(r'\.(%s)( *.*)'%cmd, s).groups()
     ...: print command, '----', extra.strip()
SomeCommand ---- Some extra stuff

In [190]: s = '.SomeCommand'

In [191]: command, extra = re.search(r'\.(%s)( *.*)'%cmd, s).groups()
     ...: print command, '----', extra.strip()
SomeCommand ----
```

### EDIT:

On your update, it seems your command never contains whitespaces, so just use `str.split` with the *maxsplit* being `1`:

```
In [212]: s = '.SomeCommand'

In [215]: s.split(' ', 1)
Out[215]: ['.SomeCommand']

In [216]: s = '.SomeCommand Some extra stuff'

In [217]: s.split(' ', 1)
Out[217]: ['.SomeCommand', 'Some extra stuff']
```

To avoid the unpacking errors (if you insist on unpacking):

```
In [228]: parts = s.split(' ', 1)

In [229]: command, extra = parts[0], "" if len(parts)==1 else parts[1]
```

Comment: Almost, but what if there is just ".SomeCommand" ? It gives me a NoneType error, almost worked though.

Comment: @user3234209 if you don't know what the command is, how do you recognize it? give us your rules ;) does the command contains spaces? or wrapped with double quotes?

Comment: @user3234209 if your command contains no spaces, see my update

Comment: I edited the answer to show the working regex. It's just a modified version of yours so you don't have to use %s and then format the string.

Comment: @user3234209 well, it's good, just a bit slower than `str.split` ;)